# convert image to video on server-side by php

Tags: php, video, converters

My visitors upload pictures to server. My website gives a sequencial name for these uploads (e.g. 0001.jpg, 0002.jpg, 0003.jpg...) What I want to do is, on request from user, I want to create a movie (preferably not flash) on server-side and send this video to client. How can I do this?

Answer (score 4):

You have to use [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/) for creatiion video on serverside. It is very flexible and really powerful tool for working with video, audio and images.

for example, to convert images image1.jpg, image2.jpg,.. into video use this command

```
ffmpeg -f image2 -i image%d.jpg video.mpg
```

To execute this command from php use [exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) or [system](http://php.net/manual/en/function.system.php) function.

PS. There are other command line utilites can be used to create video from images [ogg-slideshow](http://www.streamnik.de/74.html) and [dvd-slideshow](http://dvd-slideshow.sourceforge.net/wiki/Main_Page). They very convenient if you want to add some 
predefined transition effects or titles.