# PHP - Converting images to video using ffmpeg

Tags: php, video, ffmpeg

I am good in php but very new to ffmpeg and exec stuffs.Now I have successfully installed ffmpeg via ssh.I referred some stackoverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14052540/convert-image-to-video-on-server-side-by-php) and found below code to make video using several images.

```
<?php

echo exec('ffmpeg -f image2 -i image%d.jpg video.mpg');

?>
```

I have image1.jpg and image2.jpg in same folder.I run this php code but nothing happened...where does video.mpg gets saved ? and how to check if exec function ran successfully or how to debug it ?Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You could start with the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

Comment: yea i read that , and i run the command ffmpeg -f image2 -i image%d.jpg video.mpg ... but how to know if its successful or not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it successfully worked, *video.mpg* got saved in your current working directory. If needed you can change filenames to absolute paths.

To check if `exec()` function ran successfully you can pass the third argument to get the exit status:

```
exec('ffmpeg -f image2 -i image%d.jpg video.mpg', $output, $exit_status);
```

If successful, `$exit_status` will got `0` value, so:

```
if ($exit_status === 0) {
    // ran fine
} else {
    // failed...
}
```

If it's failling you might want to get errors on `$output`. You can move `STDERR` to `STDOUT` ignoring original `STDOUT` this way:

```
exec('ffmpeg -f image2 -i image%d.jpg video.mpg 2>&1 >/dev/null', $output, $exit_status);
```

Then you could dump `$output` to see what you got on `STDERR`:

```
if ($exit_status !== 0) {
    print implode("\n", $output);
}
```

If the *video.mpg* file already exists the command will get stuck, you might want to pass `-y` flag to `ffmpeg` to overwrite any existing file:

```
exec('ffmpeg -y -f image2 -i image%d.jpg video.mpg 2>&1 >/dev/null', $output, $exit_status);
```

Comment: I've improved my answer with some examples... Try the `system()` version and then `var_dump($exit_status, $output);` to see what happened. :)

Comment: hey awesome :) +1 , i fixed the error by debugging :) thanks a tons

Comment: @Vishnu You're welcome! I've added a further note for *file existing* issue you might face in the way. :)